# Voice recording in 8000hz,16bit,mono wav format is possiple in html5

Tags: html, voice-recording

HI I want to creating web application for voice recording  i need to capture voice in 8000hz,16bit,mono and pcm wav format it's possiple in html?

Comment: HTML alone, no. You will need some JavaScript as well.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Did You refer any javascript?